# Click outside of Carousel to return to Home webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have a webpage Carousel.html where my carousel is displayed with the following code:

```
                <div id="carouSel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" id="carousel-inneR">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img class="first-slide" src="././img/Carousel_img/Jimmy_Lannon_21.jpg" alt="First slide">
                                <div class="container">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="second-slide" src="././img/Carousel_img/Jimmy_Lannon_22.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                                <div class="container">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img class="third-slide" src="././img/Carousel_img/Jimmy_Lannon_23.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                                <div class="container">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carouSel" role="button" data-slide="prev" id="preV" >
                        <img class="left-chevron" src="././img/left_chevron.png" aria-hidden="true"/>
                    </a>
                    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carouSel" role="button" data-slide="next" id="nexT" >
                        <img class="right-chevron" src="././img/right_chevron.png" aria-hidden="true"/>
                    </a>

                    <div class="artist-name">
                        <h2>JIMMY LANNON</h2>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Then I have the following JQuery code:

```
    $(document).click(function(e) {   
    if(e.target.id !==('#carouSel')) {
        $(".carousel").hide();   
    } 
});
```

This doesn't seem to work - what I want is for the carousel to only be hidden when I click outside of it, but it gets hidden if I just click anywhere.

Comment: Add `return false;` after `$(".carousel").hide(); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I usually handle something like that. You have to make sure to listen to the body and not the document.

```
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
   $('#carouSel').hide();
});

$('#carouSel').on('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The key is to stop the bubbling of the click event in your carousel using e.stopPropagation(); That way, it will never reach the body element click listener.

Comment: This is great except the carousel controls stop working? Any way to make sure the carousel still works?

Comment: @Davtho1983 you would just need to add direct listeners to each control. If you are trying to add event delegation it won't work properly with the stopPropagation

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to check the parent ID for carouSel because at the moment you are only checking the value for the target, which could be the value for the image tag ID etc.

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('body').click(function(e) {  
                        if($(e.target).parents('#carouSel').length == 0){
                             $(".carousel").hide();   
                        } 
                    });

                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must attach click listener to the body like that:

```
$('body').click(function(e) {   
    if(e.target.id !==('#carouSel')) {
         $(".carousel").hide();   
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yuo need to add return false for stop prapagate event.

```
$(document).click(function(e) {   
if(e.target.id !==('#carouSel')) {
    $(".carousel").hide();
    return false;
}
```